# Cannot set user parameters in BackgroundSubtractorMOG2

Tags: c++, opencv, background-subtraction

OpenCV library version 2.42. I'd like to set a parameter in `BackgroundSubtractorMOG2` object, e.g.

```
BackgroundSubtractorMOG2 bgr;  

// the following doesn't work because 'nmixtures', 'backgroundRatio' 
// and 'fVarMin' are a protected members.
bgr.nmixtures = 3;   
bgr.backgroundRatio = 0.9;
bgr.fVarMin = 5; 

// the following works 
bgr.set('nmixtures', 3); 

// both of the following lines will give a run-time error 
// `Access violation reading location 0x0000000000000008.`
bgr.set("backgroundRatio", 0.9);  
bgr.set("fVarMin", 5);
```

`backgroundRatio` and `fVarMin` are parameters that control the algorithm. User should be able to change these parameters according to the [documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/video/doc/motion_analysis_and_object_tracking.html?highlight=backgroundsubtractormog2#backgroundsubtractormog2).

How can I set the parameters of `BackgroundSubtractorMOG2`?

**EDIT** As correctly mentioned in the answer below, this was a bug in OpenCV. The bug was fixed in OpenCV version 2.4.6.

Comment: In earlier versions of OpenCV `nmixtures` and other parameters used to be public but it was changed in version 2.4.

Comment: posted the question on OpenCV board. Still no answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I've just looked OpenCV source code and found interesting initialization in file `/modules/video/src/video_init.cpp`. Here it is:

```
CV_INIT_ALGORITHM(BackgroundSubtractorMOG2, "BackgroundSubtractor.MOG2",
    obj.info()->addParam(obj, "history", obj.history);
    obj.info()->addParam(obj, "nmixtures", obj.nmixtures);
    obj.info()->addParam(obj, "varThreshold", obj.varThreshold);
    obj.info()->addParam(obj, "detectShadows", obj.bShadowDetection));
```

It seems that it's possible to set only these four parameters using method `set`.

And also take a look at file `modules/video/src/bgfg_gaussmix2.cpp`, which has a `BackgroundSubtractorMOG2` class. It has the following fields:

```
float fVarInit;
float fVarMax;
float fVarMin;
//initial standard deviation  for the newly generated components.
//It will will influence the speed of adaptation. A good guess should be made.
//A simple way is to estimate the typical standard deviation from the images.
//I used here 10 as a reasonable value
```

And the value `fVarMin` (which you want to change) is set to:

```
fVarMin = defaultVarMin2
```

in both constructors. Here are all of them:

```
static const float defaultVarInit2 = 15.0f; // initial variance for new components
static const float defaultVarMax2 = 5*defaultVarInit2;
static const float defaultVarMin2 = 4.0f;
```

And interesting fact that this value is not used in any other file, so it seems that it's impossible to change it for now. You can post this issue directly to [OpenCV bugtracker](http://code.opencv.org/projects/opencv).

Comment: Is my issue `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17284712/error-in-backgroundsubtraction-mog2` is same as this ?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, `bgr.set("nmixtures",3);` should work. `BackgroundSubtractorMOG2` inherits from `cv::Algorithm`, so you use `cv:Algorithm::get` and `cv::Algorithm::set` to access those parameters. Did you try that and it doesn't work?

Comment: `bgr.set("nmixtures",3);` works but `bgr.set("bShadowDetection", false);` doesn't.

Comment: How about if you set it in the constructor like [that](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/video/doc/motion_analysis_and_object_tracking.html?highlight=backgroundsubtractormog2#backgroundsubtractormog2-backgroundsubtractormog2). Does this work?

Comment: Yeah, I guess the best option is to set all the properties in the constructor. It seems that some of parameters can't be changed even using `cv::Algorithm` interface. http://answers.opencv.org/question/1310/access-to-mog2-parameters-via-algorithm-interface/

Comment: Probably getters and setters are not defined for bShadowDetection. I think that you can use set and get for all the parameters mentioned [here](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/video/doc/motion_analysis_and_object_tracking.html?highlight=backgroundsubtractormog2#backgroundsubtractormog2)

Comment: When I do `bgr.set("fVarMin", 5);` (this is one of user defined parameters), the code compiles but I get run a time error. So it doesn't work for some reason..

Comment: Does it get set or not? What does it return using `Algorithm::get`? If it returns 5, it means that it actually works but for some reason that value causes runtime error. If this is the case, it doesn't have anything to do with the setter though. Do you get a runtime on exactly that line?

Comment: Don't think it's the value, the code crashes exactly on `bgr.set("fVarMin", 5);` line and the value of `bgr.fVarMin` doesn't change. I tried `bgr.set("fVarMin", (float)5);` but it still crashes.

Comment: I haven't read that paper, what does fVarMin represent? Did you try with other values? Does it say anything else, except for runtime error?

Comment: The error says `Access violation reading location 0x0000000000000008.` Also crashes for `bgr.set("backgroundRatio", 0.9)`. These are all user configurable parameters and the corresponding values I try to set them to are all within the allowable range (e.g. default value for `bgr.backgroundRatio` is 0.9).

Comment: @Alex It may be stupid, but have you tried bgr.set("backgroundRatio", 0.9f);

Comment: tried it - no luck. Also tried `bgr.set("backgroundRatio", (float) 0.9)` but it gives the same run-time error.

Answer (score 2):

Since these parameters are protected, a derived class can access them. I made a derived class to set all the necessary parameters.

```
struct BackgroundModel2ParameterBlock {
int nmixtures;
float backgroundRatio;
float varThresholdGen;
float fVarInit;
float fVarMin;
float fVarMax;
BackgroundModel2ParameterBlock(void) :
  nmixtures(3),
  backgroundRatio(0.6),
  varThresholdGen(6.25),
  fVarInit(256),
  fVarMin(256),
  fVarMax(9e2)
{ }
};

class BackgroundModel2 : public cv::BackgroundSubtractorMOG2 {
private:
  BackgroundModel2ParameterBlock m_param;
};

BackgroundModel2::BackgroundModel2(BackgroundModel2ParameterBlock param):
  BackgroundSubtractorMOG2(),
  m_param(param)
{
  nmixtures = m_param.nmixtures;
  backgroundRatio = m_param.backgroundRatio;
  varThresholdGen = m_param.varThresholdGen;
  fVarInit = m_param.fVarInit;
  fVarMin = m_param.fVarMin;
  fVarMax = m_param.fVarMax;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In `android`, use algorithm functions: `setDouble`, `setInt`, `setBool`:
this works:

```
mBgMog2 = new BackgroundSubtractorMOG2(mHistory,mMog2Threshold );  
mBgMog2.setInt("nmixtures" , 3);
mBgMog2.setDouble("fVarInit" , 80.0);
mBgMog2.setDouble("fTau" , 0.2);
mBgMog2.setDouble("fVarMin" , 200.0);
mBgMog2.setDouble("fVarMax" , 80.0);
mBgMog2.setBool("detectShadows",false);
```