# Error in BackgroundSubtraction Mog2

Tags: opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I am using opencv 2.4.4 and when i run this algorithm on it , it give me the error on `nmixtures` and  `bShadowDetection`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <opencv/cv.h>
#include "opencv2/features2d/features2d.hpp"
#include <opencv/highgui.h>
#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"
#include "opencv2/core/core.hpp"
#include "opencv2/nonfree/features2d.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/calib3d/calib3d.hpp"
#include  <vector>
#pragma comment (lib , "opencv_core244d.lib")
#pragma comment (lib ,"opencv_highgui244d.lib")
#pragma comment(lib , "opencv_imgproc244d.lib")
#pragma comment(lib ,"opencv_video244.lib")
using namespace cv;
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    cv::Mat frame;
    cv::Mat back;
    cv::Mat fore;
    cv::VideoCapture cap("try2.avi");
    cap >> frame;
    cv::initModule_video(); 
     cv::BackgroundSubtractorMOG2 bg(100, 16, true); // history is an int, distance_threshold is an int (usually set to 16), shadow_detection is a bool
     bg.set("nmixtures", 3);
     bg(frame, fore, -1); //learning_rate = -1 here
    std::vector<std::vector<cv::Point> > contours;
    cv::namedWindow("Frame");
    cv::namedWindow("Background");

    for(;;)
    {
        cap >> frame;
        bg.operator ()(frame,fore);
        bg.getBackgroundImage(back);
        cv::erode(fore,fore,cv::Mat());
        cv::dilate(fore,fore,cv::Mat());
        cv::findContours(fore,contours,CV_RETR_EXTERNAL,CV_CHAIN_APPROX_NONE);
        cv::drawContours(frame,contours,-1,cv::Scalar(0,0,255),2);
        cv::imshow("Frame",frame);
        cv::imshow("Background",back);
        if(cv::waitKey(30) >= 0) break;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Error's

```
error C2248: 'cv::BackgroundSubtractorMOG2::nmixtures' : cannot access protected member declared in class 'cv::BackgroundSubtractorMOG2'
error C2248: 'cv::BackgroundSubtractorMOG2::bShadowDetection' : cannot access protected member declared in class 'cv::BackgroundSubtractorMOG2'
```

When i use it like below , it didn't give syntax error , but give me error at runtime

```
bg.set("nmixtures", 3);
bg.set("detectShadows", false);
```

Error

```
Unhandled exception at 0x7617812f in WK01.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: cv::Exception at memory location 0x001de2d0..
opencv error : Bad argument (no parameter nmixture is found) in unknown function
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you paste the entire line of error here please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your displayed error says `(no parameter nmixture is found)`.  The issue here is that you've typed `nmixture` instead of `nmixtures`.

Shadow detection cannot be set using the `.set()` function; this is a bug in opencv. If you'd like to set it, you should [initialize it in your constructor](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/video/doc/motion_analysis_and_object_tracking.html?highlight=backgroundsubtractormog2#backgroundsubtractormog2-backgroundsubtractormog2).  Here is how you should initialize your background model:

```
cv::BackgroundSubtractorMOG2 bg(history, distance_threshold, shadow_detection); // history is an int, distance_threshold is an int (usually set to 16), shadow_detection is a bool
```

Comment: @Chrish , +1 , You told me that its better algorithm than others for detecting moving objects , but its just marking lines on object , but background is still visible and its in the color form , Can you please explain it , IF YOU WANT

Comment: When i write `bg.nmixtures = 3;` after `cv::BackgroundSubtractorMOG2 bg(100, 16, true);` it give me runtime error , and option for break or continue , `c:\opencv\2.4.4\build\include\opencv2\video\background_segm.hpp(145) : see declaration of 'cv::BackgroundSubtractorMOG2::nmixtures'
        c:\opencv\2.4.4\build\include\opencv2\video\background_segm.hpp(118) : see declaration of 'cv::BackgroundSubtractorMOG2'
Project : error (null) : Build errors occurred.`

Comment: @Wish_2_fly Right, don't write `bg.nmixtures = 3;`.  Instead, write `bg.set("nmixtures", 3);`.  For the foreground mask (what has changed from the background), you use `bg(frame, fore, learning_rate);`.  Then, `fore` will have what has changed.

Comment: This error i get on run time `Unhandled exception at 0x7555812f in WK01.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: cv::Exception at memory location 0x001be09c..` when i put this 'bg.set("nmixtures", 3);` `bg(frame, fore, -1);' learning rate i put is -1

Comment: How are you initializing `frame`, `fore`, and `back`?

Comment: @Wish_2_fly Your code runs perfectly fine on my system without any runtime errors.  If you are recieving runtime errors now, the issue is missing a dll or the video not actually loading (you may have the wrong path).   Link against opencv core, imgproc, video, and highgui at the very least.

Comment: no the video is there, and i played with the other codes , i update my header files , kindly check them , if any problem exists there

Comment: `"opencv_video244d.lib"`, not `"opencv_video244.lib"` if you're in debug mode.  Don't mix debug and release dlls.

Comment: I think there is error in my file background_segm.hpp in video folder ,Can you send me that from your end ?

Comment: I haven't made any changes to the original OpenCV source code, so whatever I sent would be identical to what is on opencv.org.  Can you step through the code?  Where is the error thrown?

Comment: I wanted to delete the background ,just want to extract the foreground so that i can put surf algorithm on it for feature/object detection,but this algorithm looks slow,can you tell me the better values for histroy and learning_rate and Thanks for your much help , million thanks

Comment: @Angel No its still the error , i remove it , i just take the foreground result

Answer (score 1):

It was a bug : http://code.opencv.org/issues/2168

The bug was fixed and fix will be available in 2.4.6 version (it's already available in 2.4 branch).

**UPDATE**

For your case use

```
bg.set("nmixtures", 3); 
bg.set("detectShadows", false);
```

As for linker error:

```
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol ...
```

Maybe you forgot to link with opencv_video244.lib?

Comment: You can wait for 2.4.6 version (it will be released soon) or you can build OpenCV from sources using 2.4 branch.

Comment: i did the same with my code , but still its not working , i am working with my project and i can't wait for the versions

Comment: `Unhandled exception at 0x7617812f in WK01.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: cv::Exception at memory location 0x001de2d0..`

Comment: opencv error : Bad argument (no parameter nmixture is found) in unknown function

Comment: try to call cv::initModule_video() before BackgroundSubtractorMOG2 usage.

Comment: `cv::initModule_video(); 
cv::BackgroundSubtractorMOG2 bg;`
But still getting runtime error

Comment: `bg.set("detectShadows", false);`  (not "bShadowDetection")

Answer (score -1):

OpenCV 2.4 the nmixtures are protected instead of public, so you might have to set the values for nmixtures and bShadowDetection using the constructor